# Why web view refresh in android after camera close?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am opening a URL in webview .there is `input field` initial value is blank .and a `button` in my application.on button click I am opening my camera and capture image and back to my web view to show the image.

Issue is 
Initially, the input field is blank .now I type “abc” in the input field when I click the button to capture an image.The image is shown but web view is reloaded and my input field become blank again why ?? It should persist in his state.

```
package com.example.myapp.myapplication;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
    private static final int MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE = 100;
    WebView webView;
    public static Bitmap photo;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
         webView.loadUrl("http://100.50.100.97:32671");
       // webView.loadUrl("http://115.10.74.180:30019");
        JavaScriptInterface jsInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(this);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "JSInterface");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
             photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
          //  Log.d("My map",photo,"");
            if (webView != null) {
                // webView.loadUrl("http://100.50.100.97:32671");
                webView.loadUrl("http://115.10.74.180:30019");
            }
        }
    }

    public void checkTest(){
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE);
        } else {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}


class JavaScriptInterface {
    private MainActivity activity;



    public JavaScriptInterface(MainActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void test() {
        this.activity.checkTest();
    }


    @JavascriptInterface
    public String bitMapToBase64()
    {
        if (MainActivity.photo != null) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            //add support for jpg and more.
            MainActivity.photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, byteArrayOutputStream);
            byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();

            String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

            return encoded;
        }
        return "null image";
    }


}
```

the issue is on this line

```
if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                 photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
              //  Log.d("My map",photo,"");
                if (webView != null) {
                    // webView.loadUrl("http://100.50.100.97:32671");
                    webView.loadUrl("http://115.10.74.180:30019");
                }
            }
        }
```

**why whole content is refreshed?**

Comment: `if (webView != null) {
                    // webView.loadUrl("http://100.50.100.97:32671");
                    webView.loadUrl("http://115.10.74.180:30019");
                }`
Obviously your webview is not null and as per your code it loads the url

Comment: how to prevent that

Comment: how to back to over webview after capture image

Comment: change condition to `if(webView == null)` if thts okey

Comment: ok checking then update you

Comment: but not image is not showing..!!

Comment: Did it show previously?

Comment: yes..it is showing previously

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191058/discussion-between-aswin-p-ashok-and-user944513).

Comment: I am using using react in fronent ..!!